# How do I solve the daemon timeout error "while opening volume store metadata database" using docker?

Tags: docker, nvidia

I am trying to use a GPU on a ubuntu OS via docker and NVidia drivers on a Google Cloud VM instance. I have installed docker, Nvidia drivers, and the nvidia-container-runtime packages and am attempting to add the latter to the runtime of docker. The following image is of the issue I am having.

As you see in the image, I started by removing /var/run/docker.pid and I still cannot set the runtime for docker to also point to the nvidia-container-runtime.

[image: terminal output]

I expect this to successfully add the runtime variable so that I am able to run my desired docker setup via the nvidia runtime variable for ease of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to create /etc/docker/daemon.json and insert the necessary data. I am now able to run the desired docker services. The information needed for docker to add the runtime is as follows:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check by restarting the docker service
systemctl:

$ sudo systemctl start docker
service:

$ sudo service docker start

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I have been starting/stopping docker many times to no avail, but I just solved my issue. It was something that I had missed and I am about to post the answer. Thank you for your input again!